# Every monoidal category is strictly equivalent to a strict monoidal category.

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I am reading Joyal and Street's article ["braided tensor categories"](http://ivanych.net/doc/BraidedTensorCategories_Joyal_Street.pdf). The following theorem is proved (Theorem 1.2).
Let $ C $ be a category. Let $FC$ and $F_sC$ be respectively the free monoidal category on $C$ and the free strict monoidal category on $C$. Then $FC$ is strictly equivalent to $F_sC$.

In particular, if I understand correctly, every monoidal category is strictly equivalent to a strict one.

To prove the coherence theorem for monoidal categories, it is enought to show that every monoidal category is equivalent to a strict one. (see for instance [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155208/simple-minded-coherence-of-tricategories) or [these lecture notes](http://caiwingfield.com/docs/Graphical%20notation%20for%20monoidal%20categories.pdf) ).

My question is: why is it interesting to have strict equivalence instead of equivalence?

Comment: No, it is _not_ enough to show that every monoidal category is equivalent to a strict one; in part because now you have to contend with the coherence data of a monoidal functor. Mac Lane's coherence theorem says something slightly different, which is adequately captured by the theorem concerning $F C$ and $F_s C$ you quote.

Comment: Can you provide a reference please? For instance in these [lecture notes](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/tenscat.pdf) (theorems 1.8.5 and 1.9.1) it would seem like the strictness isn't used...?

Comment: The proof in Theorem 1.9.1 is neglecting the coherence data of a monoidal functor. If you knew that there is a faithful _strictly_ monoidal embedding then the proof would work.

Comment: I'm afraid I still can't see at what step of the proof the strictness is necessary.

Comment: Just try doing an example by hand, honestly without omitting any of the isomorphisms, and you will see that a mere monoidal functor is not enough.

Comment: This comes very late on time but just to avoid any misunderstanding to future readers, the proof for 1.9.1 from the lecture notes is correct, given that the statement for the coherence theorem makes reference to a formal diagram in the category $C$ and not to the free (strict) category generated by $C$.